# How to theme components with styled-components and Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

Is there a possibility to use the **Material-UI** "theme"-prop with **styled-components** using **TypeScript**?

Example Material-UI code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
}));
```

Now I want to replace this code with styled-components.
I have tested the following implementation (and other similar implementations) without success:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  background: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [withTheme](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withtheme-component-component) to inject the theme as a prop.

```
import React from "react";
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = withTheme(styled.div`
  background: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.contrastText};
`);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledDiv>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Use theme with styled-components]

For a start on the TypeScript aspects, see this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/xyh60

This is from the [withTheme HOC](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component) portion of the documentation.

Comment: Could you go into more detail using TypeScript?

Comment: I don't use TypeScript myself, so I can't be much help there.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a similar set of requirements (MUI, styled-components, theme & typescript). I got it working, but I'm sure it could be prettier:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Theme, useTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const StyledCustomButton: React.FC<{
  theme: Theme;
}> = styled(({ ...props }) => <Button {...props}>Test</Button>)`
  && {
    padding-bottom: ${(props) => props.theme.spacing(2)}px;
  }
`;

const CustomButton: React.FC = () => {
  const theme: Theme = useTheme();
  return <StyledCustomButton theme={theme} />;
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think no intended way. If you prefer the css way of writing then maybe consider this https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#string-templates

The example is

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: `
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, 0.3);
  `,
});
```