# How to theme components with Styled-Component and Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I've tried to follow exactly what's documented here:

[How to theme components with styled-components and Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831437/how-to-theme-components-with-styled-components-and-material-ui)

```
import React from "react";
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = withTheme(styled.div`
  background: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.main};
  color: ${props => props.theme.palette.primary.contrastText};
`);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StyledDiv>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </StyledDiv>
  );
}
```

But instead of using a "standard" HTML component like above I tried against a Material-UI Button with no luck. Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong?

This is what I am trying:

**styles.ts**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

export const StyledInnerSignInButton = withTheme(styled(Button)`
    margin: ${props => props.theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)};
`)
```

**index.tsx**

```
import { StyledInnerSignInButton } from './styles';

[...]

<StyledInnerSignInButton
    type="submit"
    fullWidth
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
>
    Sign In
</StyledInnerSignInButton>
```

I'm stuck here and still a React newbie. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what's not working? Are you seeing an error or is the style being applied to the button not according to what you expect. I tried out your code [here](https://codepen.io/nahushf/pen/gOMPwWz) and it looks like it is working

Comment: Sorry, my struggle is that some themes aren't been applied. I don't get any error message, it just doesn't do anything.

A friend of mine told me that spacing is not a function, but how can I manipulate it via styled-components?

Comment: Can you try the same thing you sent [here](https://codepen.io/nahushf/pen/gOMPwWz) using React syntax?

Comment: Oh, it is in react syntax, just check the JS window and not the HTML window

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve my issue. It was due to [specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp). There are two ways to mitigate that, one is by wrapping the new component style with &&, for example:

```
export const StyledInnerSignInButton = withTheme(styled(Button)`
    && { margin: ${props => props.theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)}; }
`)
```

Or by manipulating the CSS Injection Order, as documented [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order)

In your "master" index.tsx file, you will set up your code this way:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Home from './pages/Home';

render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      {/* component name */}
      <Home />
    </StylesProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I hope that helps someone with the same problem as me.